# The operation cannot be added because the mempool already contains a conflicting operation that should not be replaced

Tags: smart-contracts

I am getting below issue while deploying SmartPy contract in ghostnet.

```
HttpResponse: Http error response: (500)
[
    {
        "kind":"temporary",
        "id":"failure",
        "msg":"Error while applying operation oo4FzTAmMBt4tZ7Hbz5HE2fgDw441umhgtHRcSgHT1R4pWt7DBS:\nError:\n  The operation oo4FzTAmMBt4tZ7Hbz5HE2fgDw441umhgtHRcSgHT1R4pWt7DBS cannot be added because the mempool already contains a conflicting operation that should not be replaced (e.g. an operation from the same manager with better fees).\n"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The current restriction only allows one manager operation per block per account. Try to wait for the previous operation to be included in a block before running a new one.

(If you are using an account whose private key is public, such as  `tz1VSUr8wwNhLAzempoch5d6hLRiTh8Cjcjb`, this may happen frequently as many people use it.)